# How to make changes in a div by targeting input element

Tags: html, css, forms

I am trying to target .div2 by focusing on input element in the following code

```
`<div class="div1">
        <div class="div2">
            <label> This is label </label>
        </div>
        <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            name="username"
            placeholder=" this is placeholder"
        />
    </div>
```

`

I cannot make changes in html, cannot use JavaScript. I can only use CSS to solve this. I something like
`input: focus + label{ font-size: 50px }`

I have tried multiple things but couldn't target label by focusing on input element. Please ask questions if any doubt.